# Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string

Tags: php, html, css, api

I am trying to create a website and making use of the YouTube API to display the most recent two uploads from my YouTube Channel. The videos are displaying correctly but the following error is displayed below them.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in D:\xampp\htdocs\ImperialSoundsWebsite\index.php:95 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\ImperialSoundsWebsite\index.php on line 95
```

Line 95 code is:

```
echo '<iframe width="1280" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $video['v_id'] .'" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
```

The full set of code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Home</title>
<html>
<header>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <!--Link to style sheet-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


    <div class="box-area">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="#">Imperial Sounds</a>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <a href="index.php">Home</a>
                <a href="genres.php">Genres</a>
                <a href="submityourmusic.php">Submit Your Music!</a>
                <a href="about.php">About Us/Contact</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<body>
   
    <div class="banner-area">
        <h2>Imperial Sounds Music</h2>
        <h3 style="color: white; font-family: poppins;">Home for the latest and best copyright free music!</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="our-story">
            <h2>Our Story</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content-area">
        <div class="content-img">
            <img src="images/logos/youtubeicon.jpg" alt="icon" />
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <p style="color: black; font-family: poppins; font-size: 28px; font-weight: bold;">Our Story</p>
            <p style="color: black; font-family: poppins; font-size: 20px; display:inline">Imperial Sounds is a Digital Copyright Free Music Promotor. We share a wide range of different genres of music to suit many different needs for music producers and content creators.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="channel-data" class="col s6">
        </div>

        <div class="row" id="video-container">

            <?php

            $API_Url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/';
            $API_Key = 'AIzaSyCZZHuMnTS8q2hXs_-aeEl_lEJcNOX3mlg';

            $channelId = 'UCk7cEDiU2CzRAgEmTUciK1A';

            $parameter = [
                'id'=> $channelId,
                'part'=> 'contentDetails',
                'key'=> $API_Key
            ];
            $channel_URL = $API_Url . 'channels?' . http_build_query($parameter);
            $json_details = json_decode(file_get_contents($channel_URL), true);

            $playlist = $json_details['items'][0]['contentDetails']['relatedPlaylists']['uploads'];

            $parameter = [
                'part'=> 'snippet',
                'playlistId' => $playlist,
                'maxResults' => '2',
                'key'=> $API_Key
            ];
            $channel_URL = $API_Url . 'playlistItems?' . http_build_query($parameter);
            $json_details = json_decode(file_get_contents($channel_URL), true);

            $my_videos = [];
            foreach($json_details['items'] as $video){
                //$my_videos[] = $video['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'];
                $my_videos[] = array( 'v_id'=>$video['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'], 
                    'v_name'=>$video['snippet']['title'] );
            }

            while(isset($json_details['nextPageToken'])){
                $nxt_page_URL = $channel_URL . '&pageToken=' . $json_details['nextPageToken'];
                $json_details = json_decode(file_get_contents($nxt_page_URL), true);
                foreach($json_details['items'] as $video)
                    $my_videos[] = $video['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'];
            }

            //print_r($my_videos);
            foreach($my_videos as $video){   
                    echo '<iframe width="1280" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $video['v_id'] .'" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
                }
            ?>

        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have `$my_videos[] = $video['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'];` That's adding strings to the `$my_videos` array.

Comment: From what you've shown, on that line, `$video` should contain only a video ID - i.e. a string, just like the error says. (That's because of the earlier line `$my_videos[] = $video['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId']`).  Not clear what you're expecting to be there instead, or where it would come from? I would think changing `$video['v_id']` to simply `$video` is likely to solve your problem though, since you seem to want to put the video ID into that URL string.

Comment: @ADyson The error indicates that `$video` should be an array with a `v_id` key, like the ones that are added in the `foreach($json_details['items'] as $video){` loop.

Comment: @Barmar yes I know...is my comment unclear?

Comment: Why do you think `$video` should contain only a video ID? It should contain an associative array.

Comment: He's expecting an array like `array( 'v_id'=>$video['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'], 
                    'v_name'=>$video['snippet']['title'] );`

Comment: Because... `$my_videos[] = $video['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId']`)`. That's what inside the foreach loop you just mentioned.

Comment: Oh...ok there are two loops like that, which inconsistently put different data structures into $my_videos. Doh.

Comment: Soooo.... would yous be able to recommend a what the change/insert for it to work?

Comment: In both your `foreach($json_details['items'] as $video)` loops you need to put the same data structure into `$my_videos`. Right now you're putting two different types of data in there (an array the first time, and a string the second time). The string version is currently causing a problem because a string doesn't have an index "v_id". Choose what you want to do, and stick to it.

Comment: P.S. I'm surprised now that the (commented-out) `print_r($my_videos);` didn't make it obvious that the data was inconsistent when you viewed that.

Comment: Thanks for the help and it is my first time working with php

Comment: @ADyson would you know how to keep the maxResult parameter working after changing the code to an array?

Comment: It's unclear how maxResult has anything to do with this problem. That's a parameter you sent to YouTube. Presumably you expected it to control how many results were returned in each request? If it didn't do what you expected, consult the youTube API docs. (P.S. It's unclear what you expected, compared to what data you actually got. Some clarity there would help.)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the two loops that add elements to `$my_videos` are adding different types of elements. The `foreach` loop adds an associative array with:

```
$my_videos[] = array( 'v_id'=>$video['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'], 
                      'v_name'=>$video['snippet']['title'] );
```

The `while` loop just adds a string with:

```
$my_videos[] = $video['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'];
```

The code with the error expects the first kind of element, not the second. You should change the second to:

```
$my_videos[] = array('v_id' => $video['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'],
                     'v_name' => $video['snippet']['title']);
```

Comment: Thank you very much I can see clearly the mistake I was making now...
First time getting into PHP and using an API.
Changing that code doesn't use the parameter 'maxResults' => '2' anymore, where would you add the additional code to use this again?